# Trying to make a webpage refresh counter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

I want to count the number of times my web page is "refreshed". Then display a message on the page along with the number of refreshes.

For e.g- on the first refresh, the following statement shows up - "1 refresh, keep going" and so on. The sentences will keep changing with the number of refreshes. I need to print up to 10 sentences at least.

Initially, I thought that I'll just put the sentences in an array and then use cookies to count the number of refreshes and then display the corresponding sentence according to the number of refreshes.
However, cookies are a problem as they store strings and not integers. I tried using the `Number()` and `parseInt()` functions but they don't seem to work and for some reason using JavaScript for this messes up my entire web page.

Then I thought of using sessions in PHP. They also seemed nice at first approach and my kind of thing (because I don't like doing anything on the client side). But they also don't work and I get half of my print statement on my web page. No counter, nothing.

I have read the previous questions.
I have tried cookies.
I have tried sessions.

My PHP file for counter -

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
}
echo "Total page views = ". $_SESSION['views'];
?>
```

My `index.html` file contains this script at the end to run the above script which is stored in a different file named `counter.php`.

```
<?php
echo "<hr><div align=\"center\">";
    include_once "counter.php"; // this will include the counter.
echo "</div>";
?>
```

However, when I load my page I only get `"; include_once "counter.php"; // this will include the counter. echo ""; ?>` at the bottom.

Any solution is welcome. Cookies or Sessions or whatever. I need to get this thing up and running.

P.S- very sorry but I can't really provide the link to my web page as I have to keep it confidential up to the 15th of February, 2017.

Comment: php not going to execute in `.html` extension. change `index.html` to `index.php` and then check. Also add `<?php session_start();?>` on top of `index.php` so that it can show session data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still achieve what you require using cookies, or even localStorage or sessionStorage. You just need to get the value on load of the page and show it, before incrementing the value when the page is reloaded. Try this:

```
<h1></h1>
<button>Refresh</button>
```

```js
var refreshes = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('refreshes'), 10) || 0;
$('h1').text('Refreshed ' + refreshes + ' time(s)');

$('button').click(function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('refreshes', ++refreshes);
    window.location.reload();
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bk8bfo4g/1/)

Comment: There is a problem. I want the counter to rest when the site is closed. `localStorage` is saving the counter value even after restarting the browser. Any fixes?

Comment: Yep - in that case replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage`. Syntax is otherwise identical. I updated the answer for you

Comment: I copied that js into a separate file and added a heading just as in the fiddle but nothing shows up on my page (yes I did link the js by script src)

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also make sure you've put the code in a document.ready handler eg. `$(function() { /* code here */ });`. jsFiddle does this for you by default

Comment: I'm getting this `ncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: That error means you haven't included jQuery.js in the page, or are attempting to run the above code before you include it

Comment: Just one last thing... Can I style that text using regular CSS? Or something else is needed?

Comment: Nope - regular CSS would be fine, eg `h1 { color: red; }`

Answer (score 2):

Use cookies there are lots of cookies plugin available like cookies.js

Edit ---

I assume you are using cookies plugin.. I've used https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

JS Code for this ---

```
$(function () {
    RefreshCode();
})

function RefreshCode()
{
    var counter = Cookies.get('counter');
    if (!counter) {
        Cookies.set('counter', 1);
    } else {
        counter++;
        Cookies.remove('counter');
        Cookies.set('counter', counter);
    }
    console.log(Cookies.get('counter'));
}
```

This is fully working example for your reference....

HTML Code for this ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="CustomCounter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this Help...

Comment: how you have used it..could you please share your code it should work..

Comment: See my edit for achieving this using Cookies... this is fully working

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tested it out and yeah it works perfectly fine!

Comment: glad to help :)